# Rerun an application when the database connection is down

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

when I run my application, I often get an error "The underlying provider failed on Open".

[image: failed on open]

I want to ask, how can I handle this error and create a `MessageBox` that show "Restart" and "Cancel" `Button` to continue the application.

Thanks before with your help.

Comment: You should read about Exceptions and Exception Handling.

Comment: @br4d where do I can read about `Exceptions` ?

Comment: @Amirul Start with googling "How to handle exceptions in c#?"

Comment: At which point of your code this error occurs?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271301/entity-framework-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to know where your code is throwing an exception and then handle it with a `try-catch` block:

```
try
{
    // Code that might throw an exception
}
catch (EntityException)
{
    // MessageBox.Show(...)
}
```

**Note** that you should always handle the most specific exception in your `catch` block.

Comment: I already have a `try catch`

`try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                if (ex.Message.ToString() == "The underlying provider failed on Open")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("provider failed");
                    this.Close();
                }
            }`

Comment: @Amirul doing a comparison with the exception's message is a very bad idea. Just drop the comparison and catch `EntityException` like I did above.

Comment: i want to restart my form when i catch that erro

Comment: If it's your main form I don't think that's possible. You can factor the logic that is connecting to the database into a method and just call that method again after an exception occurs and the user asks to restart.

Comment: If you can show us how (relative your your form's logic) you're connecting with the database we'll have a better picture.

Comment: How do I can show a messagebox to user, that ask them to restart or not

Comment: @Amirul you're asking the same question, we can't get anywhere like this. Please show us some of your code so that we know what we're facing here.

Comment: `try
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
if (ex.Message.ToString() == "The underlying provider failed on Open")
{
MessageBox.Show("provider failed");
this.Close();
}
}`

that's what i have, I think when i get an error like that, i want to show a custom messagebox

Comment: @Amirul I'm sorry but you're not being too helpful. You're repeating the same things all over again. I think your problem is comparing the exception's message as a string. You should catch `EntityException` instead. I've already said that so please try it before going on.