# EntityExeption was unhandled by user code

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s9ok.jpg)An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: Usually means the server is failing to connect to the DB. Possibly a service account issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework The underlying provider failed on Open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271301/entity-framework-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open)